# error handling for network disconnect error

Tags: python

I am using `pyowm` to get weather update after each minutes. If I disconnect my internet or low internet what error will be occure and how can i handle this error.For `try..except` method..what possible exception have to use...??
my code is....

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import pyowm
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


win=tk.Tk()



#frame_for_showing_weather.
weather_frame=Frame(win,bg='black',width='300',height='300')
weather_frame.place(x=0,y=0)

weath=Label(weather_frame,font=('Agency',100),fg='white',bg='black')
weath.place(x=10,y=10)

temp1=''
owm=pyowm.OWM('my api key')

def obs():
    global temp1
    observation = owm.weather_at_place('Barisal,BD')
    w=observation.get_weather()
    temp2=w.get_temperature('celsius')
    if(temp2!=temp1):
        temp1=temp2['temp']
        weath.config(text=str(int(temp1))+chr(176))
        print('Alhamdulillah,Yeah that is worked')
    weath.after(60000,obs)
obs()


win.mainloop()
```

please someone explain...I am new at python.

if i drop my connection this big error occure...

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1197, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\socket.py", line 575, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 445, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 367, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=read_timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 306, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self, url, "Read timed out. (read timeout=%s)" % timeout_value)
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='api.openweathermap.org', port=80): Read timed out. (read timeout=2)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyowm\commons\http_client.py", line 24, in get_json
    timeout=self.timeout, verify=self.verify_ssl_certs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 526, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='api.openweathermap.org', port=80): Read timed out. (read timeout=2)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 596, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\James Bond\Desktop\test.py", line 23, in obs
    observation = owm.weather_at_place('Barisal,BD')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyowm\webapi25\owm25.py", line 210, in weather_at_place
    _, json_data = self._wapi.cacheable_get_json(uri, params=params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyowm\commons\http_client.py", line 44, in cacheable_get_json
    status_code, data = self.get_json(uri, params=params, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyowm\commons\http_client.py", line 30, in get_json
    raise api_call_error.APICallTimeoutError('API call timeouted')
pyowm.exceptions.api_call_error.APICallTimeoutError: Exception in calling OWM web API.

Reason: API call timeouted

Caused by: None
```

how can i handle this error...?

Comment: While running it, drop your network connection and see which exception occurs.

Comment: @UtahJarhead   I added my error...but how can I handle this error..??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Handle it how you want or need. If you want to tell it to the user, show an error dialog. If you want to silently ignore it (maybe it will work next time), just ignore it silently...

Comment: And regadring possible exceptions, check documentation for `pyowm`, it should specify, what exceptions it may raise. If it doesn't, you'll have to read its source code or catch all exceptions, but the later option is generaly considered a bad practice.

Comment: [Read the official docs on exception handling.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)  In this scenario, you can just use a basic `try` / `except` block or you can catch the specific error.  `try:` / `except socket.timeout:`

Comment: @DawidFerenczy If this error occure this loop stop working.but I want If reconnect internet on my pc this loop will start working automatically.

Comment: @Rakibul Sorry, I don't know what "loop" you're referring to, you're code doesn't contain any. If you want to reconnect automatically, then you have to implement it, of course. You'll have to detect that the internet is available and re-connect your socket.